# Count the number of files older than 14 days and add to counter in batch

Tags: batch-file

In the code below, I have a FOR statement **for %%x in (c:\Test\NSC\Trace\files*.*) do set /a count+=1** That gives me a count of all records in the directory, however I want to limit that count to files that are older than 14 days old. So that if my counter =0 it will just to "SUB2" Subroutine 2.

I have tried several things to no avail. Is there a way using the FOR statement to limit my counter to the files that are older than 14 days?

```
@echo off
:: #####  Set variable values  ##### 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set date=%DATE%
set time=%TIME%
set count=0
::
:: #####  Count files older than 14 days and add to counter #####
for %%x in (c:\Test\NSC\Trace\files\*.*) do set /a count+=1
::
:: ##### Echo to screen file count and date ##### 
echo %count%
echo %date%
::
:: ##### Check number of files older than 14 days #####
IF %count%==0 (GOTO :SUB2) ELSE (GOTO :SUB1)
::
:: ##### SUB1 Subroutine to remove old files #####
:SUB1
forfiles /P "C:\Test\NSC\Trace\files" /S /M *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path && echo The Following File was Deleted @path 2>&1>> C:\Test\NSC\TraceLog\tracelog_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"
::
echo %DATE% %TIME% >> C:\Test\NSC\TraceLog\tracelog_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"
GOTO :END
::
:: ##### SUB2 Subroutine if 0 file were identified #####
:SUB2
echo There were no files found for removal
echo There were no files found for removal >> C:\Test\NSC\TraceLog\tracelog_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"
echo %DATE% %TIME% >> C:\Test\NSC\TraceLog\tracelog_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"
::
:: ##### End the Job and Exit #####
:END
REM EXIT

pause
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `FORFILES` like you are doing in `SUB1`?

Comment: I did try using FORFILES I guess I'm just not getting the syntax correct as I still cannot get an accurate file count.

Comment: Show me the `FORFILES` code you tried to count the files.

Comment: Looks like I already trashed what I had tried. If you have a suggestion I would be happy to try it

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a variable within a `FORFILES` command execution. At least not that I know of.  You have to capture the output with a `FOR /F` command.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('forfiles /D -14 /m *.*') do @set /a count+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some caveats:

1. [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) only checks the *modification date* (not *creation*, no *time*); so it depends on what you mean by *older than* (I would understand *created on or before date*...).
2. `forfiles` returns files *and* directories by default, so you need to filter for files by [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)`@isdir==FALSE` within the command line after `/C`.
3. Specifying mask `/M *.*` does not return any items that have no name extension. Hence to include files with no extension, you need to specify `/M *`.

So all this means: if you want to return all files that have been modified on the date 14 days ago or earlier, you need to use a `forfiles` command line like this:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "C:\Test\NSC\Trace\files" /M * /D -14 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo @path"
```

To finally count the returned items wrap a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) around:

```cmd
set /A "COUNT=0"
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    forfiles /S /P "C:\Test\NSC\Trace\files" /M * /D -14 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo @path"
') do set /A "COUNT+=1"
echo %COUNT%
```

---

An alternative way is to use [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), which is for sure faster than `forfiles`. This returns all files that have been modified 14 days ago or earlier, regarding the time too. The `/L` switch prevents the command to actually copy any items. A working command line would be this:

```cmd
robocopy "C:\Test\NSC\Trace\files" "C:\Test\NSC\Trace\files" *.* /L /E /IS /NP /NS /NC /NJH /NJS /MINAGE:14 /NDL
```

The switch `/NDL` avoids directories to be returned. The other `/N_` switches reduce the output so that only a pure file list is left.

To count the returned items again wrap a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) around:

```cmd
set /A "COUNT=0"
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    robocopy "C:\Test\NSC\Trace\files" "C:\Test\NSC\Trace\files" *.* /L /E /IS /NP /NS /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /MINAGE:14
') do set /A "COUNT+=1"
echo %COUNT%
```

---

In case you want to count files that have been *created* 14 days ago or earlier, both `forfiles` and `robocopy` cannot help you.

Comment: aschipfl - Thanks for your reply, that solution got me on my way. Thanks a bunch

Comment: If you supply the date with forfiles and use the + symbol it will give you files created in the last 14 days.

Comment: @Squashman, that's not true; `forfiles /D +14` returns items modified *in* 14 days (I call that a design flaw), so you'd need a time machine to use that "feature"... ;-) only `/D +0` can be useful to get items modified *today* (note the time is ignored)...

Comment: I said DATE. Not days.

Comment: /D + 04/04/2018

Comment: Robocopy can also be given a number of days or date for the min and max age options.

Comment: We can talk all day about how people understand the English language and I have been speaking it for almost 50 years. My understanding of your last paragraph of your answer is that you say forfiles and robocopy cannot iterate files newer than a specific amount of days and I say it can if you give it the date. You just calculate the current date minus x amount of days and feed that date to forfiles or robocopy with a +.

Comment: Seems you misunderstood the last sentence in my answer: what I wanted to point out is the fact that both `forfiles` and `robocopy` regard the *modification* date (time) but **not** the *creation* date (time); I was NOT talking about when something happens *after* a certain point of time.